# How to achieve this effect with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, spinner, effect

A client has asked for a spinning wheel as part of their navigation. The user is faced with the edge of the wheel with the various navigation items on there, and they spin it with a click/drag of their mouse. Whatever it stops on is what page they are presented with. The only example of this I could find to help illustrate what I want is on [this website](http://www.taxistudio.co.uk/).

I have no idea where to even begin with this effect. Is there anyone who could offer some assistance. I don't need code as I'm quite good with ActionScript 3, I just need a discussion about the way to do it as I'm stuck here.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: I need help in doing the hovering wheel. Please help me. can give me the action script 3 for hovering the wheel? Since i'm using the oval tool to create a circular wheel, i need as3 to insert in my flash cs4 to make it hover when the mouse click and dray on it. Thank you

Ferra.

Comment: Hi, I used PaperVision 3D to do this - http://papervision2.com/tutorial-list/

Comment: I used this tutorial and just changed the position of the wheel and the images that appear on it http://papervision2.com/a-simple-papervision-carousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decompiled the swf. He's using Alternativa 3D but you could just as easily use Away3D or Papervision. Personally I prefer Away. Just make a 3D ring and texture the edge.

Comment: We have a 3D guy in the office so if he can get me a Collada compatible model we may have a winner here. Cheers

Comment: I've done PV3D before so maybe this'll be the solution for me.

Comment: could you tell me what Decompiler do you use?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's that difficult:

- calculate the velocity as a diff of two mouse positions
- don't use real 3D just smart masking, narrower on the top and bottom
- use some smart transparent overlays to generate those shadows and highlights, they don't move at all
- transform the height of the thumbnail according to cosine function - it's 100% in the middle and 0% on the top and bottom.

Otherwise you may try Papervision3D but I strongly recommend not to, it would overcomplicate your project.

good luck

Daniel

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this but I wasn't sure. Cheers

Comment: @Daniel Hanly I have used fake 3D couple times before and I find it less complicated than dealing with 3rd party frameworks. Also the compiled file will be much smaller ;).